# Making sublists from a list with sum of sublist being less than a given number

Tags: python, list

I have 2 inputs as:

```
p = 7
s = [2 2 8 1 3]
```

I know how to get basic list subsets by `itertool.combinations` but want I want is contiguous sublists with each sublist with sum of their elements being less than `p`.

So output will be:

```
 [2],[2,2],[2],[1],[1,3],[3]
```

Here I got 6 such sublists where for each sublist, `sum(sublist) < p`.

Comment: does it need to be in that specific order?

Comment: Why not `[2, 2, 1]` and `[2, 1, 3]` part of your list as they are also less than 7?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri "contiguous", the OP mentioned it in the question

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
p = 7
s = [2,2,8,1,3]
ans=[]
for i in xrange(len(s)):
    for j in xrange(i,len(s)):
        if sum(s[i:j+1])<p:
            ans.append(s[i:j+1])
print ans
```

output:

```
[[2], [2, 2], [2], [1], [1, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: which you can write as a list comprehension: `ans = [s[i:j+1] for i in xrange(len(s)) for j in xrange(i,len(s)) if sum(s[i:j+1]) < p]`

Answer (score 0):

If you like one liners, you can try this:

```
>>> sum([[s[i:j+1] for j in range(i, len(s)) if sum(s[i:j+1])<p] for i in range(len(s))], [])
[[2], [2, 2], [2], [1], [1, 3], [3]]
```

The `sum(list_of_lists, [])` is flattening the list of lists created in the list comprehension, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/3375713).

Or you can use what Julien Spronck mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917829/how-to-make-subarrarys-from-the-list#comment69049661_40917900), which is far superior.

Comment: I have been trying to come up with a list comprehension for quite some time now, instead of going to sleep this late at night. It is 1:30AM here now. My head is definitely not in a good shape.